# How do you calculate reading on a voltmeter, without voltage given in the question?

Tags: circuit-analysis, homework

[image: Image of question and schematic]

How do you calculate reading on voltmeter without voltage given?

Comment: You have a given voltage, the 2V across the 4 Ohm resistor. Use it as a starting point.

Comment: What current through the 4 ohm resistor?

Comment: This is not Chegg. We don't hand out homework solutions.

Answer (score 1):

In your circuit it is given the voltage across the 4ohm resistor from that you can get the current in the circuit. Since it is a series connection current will be safe in every element. Taking that current calculate eac so across all resistors. Adding all Voltage drops will give you the total battery voltage applied

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the meters. Pretend that the voltmeters aren't there, and that the ammeter is just a plain wire. Starting from the top of the battery, the circuit has a 6-ohm resistor, then a 4-ohm resistor, then a 3-ohm resistor, and then goes back to the bottom of the battery. That's just a series circuit with three resistors.

The circuit diagram tells you that there's a 2V drop across the 4-ohm resistor. From that you can calculate the current flowing through the 4-ohm resistor. And because this is a series circuit, the same current is flowing through the rest of the circuit. Knowing that current, you can calculate the voltage drop across the 6-ohm resistor and across the 3-ohm resistor. Add them all up and you know the total voltage in the circuit. That comes from the battery.